# Preventing SQLite query from doing USE TEMP B-TREE FOR GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE user_records (
pos smallint PRIMARY KEY, 
username MEDIUMINT unsigned not null,
anime_id smallint UNSIGNED NOT NULL,  
score tinyint not null,
scaled_score DECIMAL(1,5) not null
)
```

with indexes

```
(anime_id,username,scaled_score)
(username,anime_id,scaled_score)
(username)
(anime_id)
```

I know those last two were redundant I was just testing

And lastly here is my query:

```
select aggregate_func(score2) scores,anime_id from 
(select anime_id as anime_id2,username as username2,scaled_score as score2  from user_records where anime_id in(666)) 
inner join  
(select anime_id,username,scaled_score from user_records)
where  username = username2  group by anime_id  order by scores desc limit 1000;
```

The goal of this query is to run an aggregation function on every combination of scores a user has given to a specified show (666 in this case) and all other shows in the table. I have tried every type of join SQLite supports, which isn't many, and reordering the select statements, but the outcome is always the same except with a cross join with the unconstrained select first, which takes a very long time for obvious reasons. I am confident after executing each part separately that the part taking the most time is the USE TEMP B-TREE FOR GROUP BY. My goal is for the query planner to somehow use an index for the GROUP BY, but no matter what I try it chooses B-TREE, and the grouping process takes exponentially longer depending on the size of the result set from the join.

For reference, this table has 70,000,000 rows of user show ratings and the GROUP by often has to work on  millions of joined rows. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're grouping on the results of a join, so probably no way to avoid creating a temp table in the query

Comment: You can drop those indexes on just username and anime_id btw; they're redundant considering the other two. And pos should be an integer primary key to avoid another pointless index....

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be really helpful.  For instance, your description mentions "show" but there is no such column in the table you show.

Comment: I forgot to specify a few things. The shows i referred to are from the anime_id column @GordonLinoff and i do have the primary key on pos